# How to: live reload next project when shared library component changes using tailwind

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, monorepo

I have 2 NextJS projects using tailwind, typescript and webpack, called "webA" and "webB". These will be deployed on the same domain.

I also have a third react project for sharing components called "library". "webA" and "webB" will be importing components from "library"

All of the above set up with yarn workspaces.

Each project works perfectly on its own, tailwind works fine with live reload, no issues there. Each project has their own tailwind config, postcss config, tsconfig currently (I'd like to merge these into a single one as well - but that's not what this is about I think)

I can import components and they work flawlessly, when I make a change in "library", "webA" recompiles, apart from any classes applied with tailwind:

When I import a component in "webA"/"webB" from "library", I have to manually run postcss within "library" and include the generated css file in the root of "webA"/"webB" otherwise the tailwind classes won't work.
Then, if I change the component in "library", the tailwind styles don't get applied unless I re-run the postcss command manually.

How could I include the shared components with tailwind properly and have it update when live reloading?

Comment: `postcss` has a `--watch` option use it, and keep it running in another shell. You'll have to restart it only on errors I guess.

Comment: thanks, that solved my problem. I've added postcss --watch to package.json so I run the library in watch mode alongside the other applications while developing, works like a charm